# Do any Star Trek characters play rock band instruments?

Tags: star-trek, music, rock-music

We see quite a few Star Trek characters play orchestral instruments - Riker plays the trombone (although jazz rather than classical is his thing), Data plays the violin, Kim plays the clarinet and later takes up the saxophone. Are there any characters who play "rock" instruments - electric guitar, bass guitar etc.?

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Musical_instrument

Comment: Picard plays the electric guitar; https://images.app.goo.gl/6VwbJ7vzSMEBazo49

Comment: Michael Dorn plays the bass guitar IRL

Comment: Saxophones were often used in rock and roll music back in the 1950s.

Comment: Riker also plays a piano in one episode.  (I forget the context, but he was playing next to a 4-armed woman in a bar, and she made some comment about "Just what I need, another pair of hands".)  Pianos are often involved in rock music, so that might count.

Comment: The violin has certainly been used as an electric rock instrument (see Kansas).

Comment: Define "rock". I consider ska a type of rock music, and the trombone is often featured heavily in ska music. If you mean to limit the instruments to the original "rock" instrumentation, that's pretty much just electric guitar, the instrument that _defined_ rock music as different from its predecessors. Yet, even at the birth of rock & roll, other traditional instruments were in use: upright bass, piano, drums, sax. In the right hands, just about any instrument is technically a "rock" instrument, even the flute (Ian Anderson) and the violin (aka fiddle, Charlie Daniels), etc.

Comment: Didn't Tom Paris and some of the other Voyager crew try to impress another race of aliens with their music in one episode? I seem to recall them being unimpressed with rock but in love with classical orchestra?

Comment: Actually, scratch that - I must have been thinking about this episode, which doesn't mention Paris (instead it mentions Harry Kim's band) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuoso_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)

Comment: Does [a flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jethro_Tull_(band)) count?

Comment: In VOY, [Real Life](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Real_Life_(episode)#Act_Two) we don't actually see instruments, but the doctor's holographic son is heard listening to "Klingon Music", which sort of sounds like a mashup of heavy metal and [Stomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stomp_(theatrical_show)).

Comment: T-shirt immediately purchased.

Comment: Now I really want to see a picture or maybe even a full video of Data, Geordi, Worf, and Riker rocking out on some [Rock Band instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Band#Instrument_peripherals).

Comment: Voyager's Doctor plays "the voice", that's definitely a rock instrument

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Unnamed holographic musician

### Electric Guitar

Depending on your definition of 'Star Trek character' - we do see a presumably holographic member of Vic Fontaine's band playing an electric guitar in the DS9 episode "[His Way](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/His_Way_(episode))".

There is also a 'modern' (period) drum kit in the band.

[image]

---

## LQ "Sonny" Clemmonds

### Acoustic Guitar

Recently unfrozen Earth musician L.Q. 'Sonny' Clemmonds held an acoustic guitar on the Enterprise-D in the TNG S1 episode "[The Neutral Zone](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Neutral_Zone_(episode))". We can presume he is more of a country music player, rather than 'rock' but the genres are often mixed and share similiarities (certainly compared to jazz / classical)

[image]

---

## Unnamed wedding band member

### Electric guitar

At the Riker wedding in the TNG film Star Trek: Nemesis, an electric guitar and "space" drum kit are seen

[image]

Comment: An excellent find. It stretches the idea of a "character" to breaking point since the guitarist is basically just hologrammatic wallpaper, but it's seen on screen which gets a tick from me.

Comment: @Valorum - well that's why I said "presumably" ;) - in the same clip we see Odo playing the piano. The guitarist could be a Starfleet engineer on his break (I kid - it's almost certainly a hologram)

Comment: Also, the Vic Fontaine performance is clearly jazz, not rock, so maybe not what the OP was looking for?

Comment: an electric guitar would fall under the question as asked, which was about instrument itself, not the source music played in the episode @DarrelHoffman :)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If you exclude instruments used in Jazz then what are you left with? According to the 'Typical instruments' section on wikipedia ([Jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz), [Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_music)), nothing.

Comment: @CrowTRobot - Yeah, I just think the intent of the question was probably meant to be more "Does anybody play rock *music*?"  Even though as worded it seems to only care about the instruments.  You'd have to ask the OP what they intended, though.

Answer (score 10):

Within the main canon of films and TV shows, we don't, as far as I'm aware, see any "rock" instruments being played by a named character.

Probably the closest we get is Adam (TOS: The Way to Eden) which is a sort of modified [mentally-controlled acoustic guitar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pNQYHvhnms). Commander Daren plays [an electric piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4y_oWBiwAo) in TNG: Lessons, but we only see it used as a classical piano so it's not clear if it can also be used as a generic sounds keyboard.

---

Moving down the canon scale, Wesley Crusher plays an electric [Telecaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fender_Telecaster) guitar in [TNG: The Sky's the Limit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sky%27s_the_Limit)

> In a store off a side street on Telegraph Hill, Wes bought a battered reproduction of an old electric guitar and found something that could, for a little while at least, take his mind off things. The Telecaster was at least a hundred years old, modeled on an original instrument from the middle of the twentieth century. He picked up the ability to read music as easily as a plant drew in sunlight, and in the residential block where he lived, Crusher would sit on the balcony in warmer days and write music in his head, composing strings that bled out all the angry and the sad inside him. He played in coffee shops; he made, if you could call it that, something of a minor name on San Francisco’s scene. People who came to see him left with their emotions stirred; the slight, moody teenager played with muted brilliance. He made the Telecaster sing. There were some girls and some good times, but mostly he was drifting, drifting with the music.

---

Comment: Jono the human (but raised by aliens) plays alien rock music in Picard's quarters

Comment: @NKCampbell - Indeed. And Tom Paris has it on his jukebox

Comment: I found an electric guiatar on DS9 @Valorum :D

Comment: you wouldn't count Sonny as a named character playing a rock instrument (granted it's an acoustic guitar) - especially considering he's a professional performer? Tough to say since we don't know his exact musical style but he is named. He seems cut from a Johhny Cash / Buck Owens type cloth. Maybe the edit could be 'named crew-member'? I think it's worth keeping as a note for your answer

Comment: @NKCampbell - As you've said, he got an acoustic guitar and appears to be some sort of country star. Since he could have had *any* guitar, it stands to reason that he's most comfortable with a non-electric variety

Comment: fair enough - I'm just a low milage pit woofie and not very knowledgable about such things

Answer (score 2):

Lt Cmdr Nella Darren plays an electric keyboard in TNG S06E19: Lessons.

[image]

Comment: this is already addressed in Valorum's answer 9 hours ago :)

Comment: It's also worthy of note that it's (as far as we know) an electric *piano*, not a keyboard synthesiser

Comment: @NKCampbell Ah, I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Spock's [Vulcan harp](https://youtu.be/OptLgGtZ9_E) is probably the closest you get.  It does have knobs on it, like an electric guitar, and he plays a jam with space hippies that, while you can't exactly call it good rock music, is certainly not jazz, classical, or country either.

Comment: His harp is clearly a stringed (acoustic) instrument.

Comment: Spock n Roll perhaps ..... but not rock

Comment: At least they weren't playing "The Ballad Of Bilbo Baggins" :-)

Comment: @Valorum It has knobs that he clearly fiddles with while playing, and a horizontal piece near the base of the strings that might be a "pickup".  Just because it's wireless doesn't mean it's not electric.  (And who says you can't play rock on an acoustic instrument anyway?)

Comment: ..and it is called 'unplugged'.

Comment: @valorum it's clearly a stringed instrument, as is an electric guitar. You have no way to know it's acoustic only, and visual evidence suggests otherwise.